# Configure, build and install PHP 5.3.13 on Centos 7.2

Tags: php, centos7, php-5.3

I am trying to install PHP 5.3.13 on Centos 7.2. Finally got `./configure` to work after installing a few devel-dependencies. But when running `make` I get the following error:

```
/usr/src/php-5.3.13/ext/dom/node.c: In function 'dom_canonicalization':
/usr/src/php-5.3.13/ext/dom/node.c:1898:21: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
    ret = buf->buffer->use;
                     ^
In file included from /usr/src/php-5.3.13/main/php.h:38:0,
                 from /usr/src/php-5.3.13/ext/dom/node.c:26:
/usr/src/php-5.3.13/ext/dom/node.c:1900:40: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
     RETVAL_STRINGL((char *) buf->buffer->content, ret, 1);
                                        ^
/usr/src/php-5.3.13/Zend/zend_API.h:547:20: note: in definition of macro 'ZVAL_STRINGL'
   const char *__s=(s); int __l=l;  \
                    ^
/usr/src/php-5.3.13/ext/dom/node.c:1900:5: note: in expansion of macro 'RETVAL_STRINGL'
     RETVAL_STRINGL((char *) buf->buffer->content, ret, 1);
     ^
make: *** [ext/dom/node.lo] Error 1
```

I must admin that I'm out of my comfort zone on this one and have no idea what to do. Have anyone else experienced this and know a solution? Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

edit: Here is the build command

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysql-sock=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock --with-openssl --with-curl --enable-pdo --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd --with-apxs2=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs --with-zlib --enable-zip --with-gd --with-freetype-dir --with-jpeg-dir --enable-exif --enable-mbstring --enable-soap --with-mcrypt --with-zlib-dir --with-imap --with-imap-ssl --with-kerberos --with-apxs2=/usr/sbin/apxs --with-libdir=lib64
```

Comment: Not really a solution, but configured and built PHP 5.3.28 without any issues. So this question is kind of solved :) But would really like to see what is causing this issue.